# Azure DevOps buids failing all of sudden and issue looks to be auto-updated NPM version

Tags: npm, azure-devops

The build is failing with:

> "Error: Npm failed with return code: 9009"

When we look at, here's what we noticed:

```
Till date  (where there were no issues), build used to run on nmp 6.9.0 and node v10.16.3
```

[image: Screenshot of NPM install log where build was Successful]

Since the build started failing, we noticed the versions got auto-upgraded to `npm/6.12.0 node/v12.13.0`.

[image: as issue got stared, we noticed updated version of npm and node]

Please advise how to revert back to older versions, or do if we need to see this issue in a different dimension?

Comment: Are you using the hosted agent or a private agent?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops

Comment: Please don't post images of text/code.

Comment: @DanielMann we are using Azure Hosted agent.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Nojd.js tool installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/node-js?view=azure-devops) task to specify the version you want. Then set the Version Spec as below.
[image]

You will get the `node/v10.16.3` and `npm/6.9.0`.
[image]

You should add this task before the npm task. If not, the default version of node.js and npm would be below.
[image]

If your project can build successfully in local, you can use self-hosted agent to build.

Hope this helps.